# Etymologie von "forschen", "Forschung"

Tags: etymology

Kennt jemand die Herkunft von *forschen*?

Ich kann nichts Ähnliches im Englischen finden, aber es gibt *forska* auf Schwedisch.

Comment: Das schwedische Verb heißt "forska".

Comment: Schwedisch _forska_ ist aus dem Deutschen entlehnt (laut SAOB).

Comment: Es wäre hilfreich zu erwähnen, daß SAOB für Svenska Akademiens ordbok steht.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laut **Duden, Band 7, Herkunftswörterbuch** kommt *forschen* von der indogermanischen Wurzel ****per[e]kʲ-***, die so viel wie *fragen, bitten* bedeutet. (Anmerkung zur Notation: Anstatt des hochstestellten ʲ verwendet der Duden einen übergesetzten Bogen zur Kennzeichnung eines palatalen *k*-Lautes. Mir gelang es aber nicht, das hier zu reproduzieren.)

Das Wort soll laut Duden ursprünglich nur im hochdeutschen Sprachgebiet gebräuchlich gewesen sein. Unter anderem ist *forschen* mit lateinischem *poscere (fordern, verlangen)* urverwandt.

Ein paar (wie ich finde) interessante Ergänzungen:

- Das Wort *forsch* hat damit gar nichts zu tun, sondern kommt seinerseits über französisch *force* von lateinisch *fortis (kräftig, stark, fest)*.
- Obige indogermanische Wurzel hat auch *wühlen, aufreißen* bedeutet. Davon kommt z. B. *die Furche*, *das Ferkel*, lat. *porca*, engl. *pork*.
- Die Wurzel hat eine Bedeutungserweiterung erfahren von *wühlen* über *suchen* zu *fragen*.